# Android - Bundle is not null after second call of onCreate()

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

I have a very weird problem... if i call the code on my nexus 5 I get a bundle(Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=36] ???) but the bundle should be null! its just on my nexus 5 on other devices the method intent.getExtra() is null!

any suggestions to fix this problem?

```
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null) {
        String test = extras.toString();
        Toast.makeText(this, "why??! " + test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); }
```

the second time i open the app the extra isnt null it is Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=36]. whats wrong here?

Comment: Why do you think it "should" be null?

Comment: because i didnt added a extra... and on other devices it works correctly...

Comment: apparently there are stuff in it. look at the content of the stuff, it may tell you where it comes from

Comment: Remember that you pass the bundle up to super.onCreate() that extra data may be used there.

Comment: i dont get it why it works on the first call but not after the second? it does nothing on super.onCreate()... it should be null but its not

Comment: why you have extras.toString(), if you pass smth you get it extras.getStringExtra("key");

Comment: yea th extras.toString() is just to test because it fails...  i do if(extras.getString("notification").equals("blabla")) { ... but if i do the app crashes on the second call because bundle isnt empty and intent isnt added...

Comment: first i need to test if the bundle isnt empty and it should be empty so my method inside if(extras != null) should not be called..thats my problem

Comment: you need to check if(extras.getString("notification")!=null && extras.getString("notification").equals("blabla") ){ }, then it will not crash

Comment: @Lastone, show code how you start this activity.

Comment: @GjokoBozinov Thanks this fixed my problem..but i find it very weird that it worked on other devices but not on the nexus 5 with the test bundle != null... anyways thanks dude

Comment: sure, you are welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate the keyset to see what is being added to the bundle. It might also be interesting to see what isEmpty() on the bundle returns on the Nexus.

If you are checking for an extras that you have added to the intent, your null may work on most devices. If the bundle is not null, (the Nexus workaround) you may have to add secondary check to see if the key you expect is there.

Comment: yea I added both now. I checked if its not null and then checked if my string is added to the extra...

Comment: Just curious, did you iterate the keys on the non-null bundle to see what it contained?